# how to block Arduino code until a certain event?

Tags: arduino-uno

i am tring to enter a series of numbers using "keypad" to different variables..when simulate the code on proteus it only took the first "getkey()" function and ignored the rest .. 
SO,
How can i block an arduino code until a key is pressed by keypad, in other words prevent the rest of code from being executed before a key is pressed

Comment: Please post your code here. We don't have crystal balls here :)

Comment: And a wiring diagram or schematic, since this is hardware-based as well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the "keypad" is implemented. If you've got it hooked up to a hardware interrupt, then you only need to add an interrupt handler for that event.

On the other hand, the more "straight-forward" implementation is that you have to poll the pins to see if a key was pressed.  Simply do that in a loop until you see a key press, call your event-handler method, and then continue to loop.

Comment: thanks a lot, I used waitForKey() function from keypad library and it worked correctly :)